# wkhtmltopdf/laravel-snappy not rendering header and footer

Tags: laravel, apache, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, laravel-snappy

I was working on a laravel project on windows using xampp but switched to ubuntu after, my pdf generation code suddenly broke without any changes.
I installed laravel-snappy and pointed it to the wkhtmltopdf paths but suddenly headers and footers are not getting rendered.
This is my controller code

```
public function createPDF(){
        $userData = $this->getUserData(); //query and returns all users and their relations
        $pdf = App::make('snappy.pdf.wrapper');
        $footer = \view('supporting.footer')->render();
        $header = \view('supporting.header')->render();
        $userData = \collect([$this->userData[1]]); //just for faster rendering and testing
        $pdf->loadView('orders', ['users' => $userData])
        ->setOption('margin-top', '20mm')
        ->setOption('margin-bottom', '20mm')
        ->setOption('minimum-font-size', 25)
        ->setOption('header-html', $header)
        ->setOption('footer-html', $footer);
        $pdf->save($this->path);
}
```

my header view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div style="background: blanchedAlmond;color:green;">My Header is amazing<div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my footer view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="background: blanchedalmond; color:green;">Copyright &copy; 2020</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My orders view: (just some basic tables)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Order Layout</title>
    <style>
        *{
            font-family: cursive;
        }

        .wrapper {
            display: block;
        }

        .invoice {
            display: block;

            width: 80%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            margin-top: 10px;
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            background: #d3d3d3;
            page-break-inside: avoid !important;
            padding-left: 20px;
        }

        .order-items {
            padding-left: 100px;
        }

        .table {
            width: 90%;
            align-self: center;
            border: 1px solid black;
            page-break-inside: avoid !important;
            orphans: 15;
        }
        .table>* {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <main class="wrapper">
        @foreach ($users as $user)

        @php
        $orders = $user->orders //just for renaming
        @endphp
        @foreach ($orders as $order)
        
        <div class="invoice">
            @php
            $sum=0;
            @endphp
            <h2>{{$user->name}}: {{$order->id}}</h2>
            <div class="order-items">
                <table class="table" border="1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Product Name</th>
                            <th>Unit Price</th>
                            <th>Qty</th>
                            <th>subtotal</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach ($order->products as $product)
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                {{$product->name}}<br>
                            </th>
                            <td>{{$product->unit_price}}</td>
                            <td>{{$product->pivot->quantity}}</td>
                            @php
                            $sum+= $product->pivot->quantity*$product->unit_price
                            @endphp
                            <td>{{$product->pivot->quantity*$product->unit_price}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="3">Total:</th>
                            <td>{{$sum}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
        @endforeach
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

This is my apache config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin user@email.com
    DocumentRoot /home/frapto/frapto/pdf-mock/public
    ErrorLog "/home/frapto/example.error.log"
    CustomLog "/home/frapto/example.access.log" combined
    <Directory "/home/frapto/frapto/pdf-mock/public">
        Options -Indexes
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is the pdf layout comparison is on:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvMvT.jpg

No headers and footers getting generated, and table headers are not repeated when table is broken across pages

I have not changed anything in the code, I have no idea why it suddenly broke and how can i fix it? I tried multiple css properties, routes, and everything i could find and had no luck with any.

I'm open to switching libraries. Though my pdf may be large (currently 3000 pages roughly but may grow or shrink), dompdf simply doesnt work, tcpdf has unclear documentation, and mpdf is too slow. All I want to generate is are divs/tables (and their css) with header and footer on each page.

Thank you

EDIT:: it turned out I just needed to install the qt patched version of wkhtmltopdf library rather than the normal one

Comment: Did you try by render the whole page before make PDF?

Comment: @SachinKumar what do you mean? I want to generate it on the server side, not on the client side. Headers and footers cannot be rendered in browser because there is no concept of pages (they display if I include them though, but they would no longer be header and footer at that time)

Comment: You need to look up 'PRINT', thead and tfoot. Put your footer and header in them, respectively.